# Use of mongo.code.create to construct array argument to $add

Tags: mongodb, rmongodb

I have MongoDB documents like the following:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"56d810f5c91e6779a38386b8"},
 "timestamp": {"$numberLong":"1457000674750"}}
```

I am constructing an aggregration pipeline which should contain the following `$project` segment:

```
{"$project": 
    {"date": {"$add": ["new Date(3600000)", "$timestamp"]}}
}
```

This works in MongoDB shell, but I can't get it to work with `rmongodb`. For instance, the following gives error 10 (BSON invalid) when included in my pipeline:

```
mongo.bson.from.list(list(
"$project"= list("date"=list("$add"=list( mongo.code.create("new Date(3600000)"), "$timestamp")))
))
```

I'm pretty sure the problem relates to the code (`new Date(3600000)`) and/or its inclusion in an array which is in turn an argument to `$add`. I suppose I can construct the BSON buffer the "old way", but what I'm looking for is how to do this with `mongo.bson.from.list` and/or `mongo.bson.from.JSON`.

Comment: Ahh, looks like you have been looking at other answers here. The `new Date(number)` things you are seeing are about contructing a `Date` object "externally" to being fed through the driver. That happens to be the JavaScript invocation of a `Date` object, and the general intent is to be converted to however you do that in your language. So not how you would do that here, nor is your intent fully clear. Your `"timestamp"` appears to just be a number, so what are you expecting to "add"? I think you mean 1 hour in millicseconds, which would really just be the number here, and not the `Date`

Comment: Short version. 1. You are doing it the wrong way, you don't want a `code` object, nor can you inject JavaScript into the aggregation framework ( code samples are actually evaluating "before" pipeline submission ). 2. Not sure what you are asking, but appear to be trying to add a number to a number, but being confused thinking it's a date.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, which pointed at the answer. My intent was to create a timezone-adjusted Date object (which can be more easily used in a subsequent group operation) from a Unix-epoch timestamp, and this method from SO worked in the shell. By substituting `ISOdate(1970, 01, 01, hour=0, tz="CET")`, instead of that "code", my original example works. If you wish to post this as an answer, I will approve it! Thanks again.

Comment: Then what you acutally want is your language equilavent of "epoch" or `Date(0)` to be sent in to be added to the already present numeric representation of a timestamp. If you want to "adjust for timezone" ( CET would be 1 hour ) then just add the time directly in milliseconds ( no date required). But I'm going to disagree with you on the `$group` since "numeric" is by far the "easiest" to deal with. So not are you only doing it wrong here, but also doing it for the wrong eventual reason. How do you want to `$group` this really?

Comment: A numeric type will certainly not be the easiest here, since the goal is to aggregate by calendar week, month, and/or day. In any case, that is not the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, it's not "JavaScript Code" that needs to be used to represent a BSON Date for injection, but rather whatever the native format is for a `Date` in the language environment.

So in `r`, you can use the following sort of constructor to get the `Date` as of epoch:

```
as.POSIXct("1970-01-01",tz="GMT")
```

So in the example of doing a BSON Date conversion on a numeric value and extracting the [`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) from that:

```
pipeline <- list(
  mongo.bson.from.list(list(
    '$project' = list(
      'test' =  list( '$year' = 
        list( '$add' = list (
          '$timestamp',
          as.POSIXct("1970-01-01",tz="GMT"),
          3600000
        ))
      )
    )
  ))
)
```

That said, there is nothing stopping you from just applying the basic math directly to the numeric value, just as an operator example to the serialized notation:

```
{ "$project": {
    "test": {
        "$add": [
            { "$divide": [
                { "$subtract": [
                    { "$add": [ "$timestamp",3600000 ] },
                    { "$mod": [ 
                        { "$add": [ "$timestamp", 3600000 ] }, 
                        1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
                    ]}
                ]},
                1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
            ]},
            1970
        ]
    }
}}
```

Also works out the current "year", and the same sort of operations can be applied to any part of a date, be it the current "year" of "dayOfYear" or anything.

Also note that `$project` usage is not really recommended if you intend to `$group` as you would be better off just using your "conversions" directly into the grouping `_id` rather than in a separate pipeline stage, for performance reasons in avoiding another pipeline pass.

The only time it would really be necessary to `$add` to a `Date` would be in the final output of a converted *"millisecond from epoch"* value in "output" where you wanted a BSON Date rather than the numeric value.